# How to restrict users to put a future date in NetSuite custom Date field?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

is it possible to restrict user from entering a future date in a netsuite field?

Usercase:
to restrict user from adding a future date in **shipment receiving** date. This field should be either today or any past date but not future.

if anyone have an idea please reply.

Comment: A client script on the record can be used to do validation. With SuiteScript 2.x for example you could use code in `validateField` to reject values for that field past the current date.

Comment: Seconding the answer above^

Answer (score 2):

Both of the following would work in a client script.

This defines the validation function that is executed when a field is changed by a user or client call.

```
  function validateField(context) {
    var curRec = context.currentRecord;
    var fieldName = context.fieldId;
    if (fieldName === 'date') { //replace "date" with your field id
      var recDate = curRec.getValue({fieldId: fieldName});
      var today = new Date();
      if (recDate > today){
        alert('You cannot enter a future date');
        curRec.setValue({
          fieldId: 'date',
          value: null
        });
      }
      return true;
    }
```

This defines the function that is executed when a field is changed by a user or client call.

```
  function fieldChanged(context) {
    var curRec = context.currentRecord;
    var fieldName = context.fieldId;
    if (fieldName === 'date'){ //replace "date" with your field id
      var recDate = curRec.getValue({fieldId: fieldName});
      var today = new Date();
      if (recDate > today){
        alert('You cannot enter a future date');
        curRec.setValue({
          fieldId: 'date',
          value: null
        });
    }
```